# In Wakenhyrst, does Maud do this?

Tags: wakenhyrst

In the novel *Wakenhyrst* by Michelle Paver, is it possible that the character Maud actually murdered Clem Walker? We only have Maud's own account that what occurred was at her father's hand. We know she was an unreliable narrator from the wet fronds her father kept finding, and it occurred to me that she really played a greater role in his descent into madness than she admits to in her own account.

Comment: I've prodded the author for a response. Hopefully we'll hear back